# Configuring generator to generate .scss file instead of css

Tags: generator, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm currently playing with Rails 3.1 RC4, and when I try to generate a scaffold:

```
rails generate scaffold animal
```

I notice that it creates a CSS file in:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/animals.css
```

I was expecting it to generate an `animals.scss` instead.

Am I missing something?

PS: I got Haml to generate correctly following the instruction from [here](http://blog.danielfischer.com/2011/04/18/quickstart-guide-to-using-compass-haml-sass-scss-with-rails-3/).

Comment: It must be related to this commit. https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/74ade51eee5a7f975f98ab2f28c77f1a10119ff5#comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On May 24, 2011, SCSS generators were moved out from Rails, and put into Sass Railtie.

See this [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/74ade51eee5a7f975f98ab2f28c77f1a10119ff5#diff-0).

This means in your application, you need to include `sass-rails` gem in your Gemfile to get the generator working correctly. In other words, it's not enough to simply include `sass` gem to get the generator working.

When SCSS is finally generated, your stylesheet will look something like `mystylesheet.css.scss`.

By default, SCSS is used.